# Generating a nice web documentation from .pdf or .tex

Tags: latex, documentation-generation

I wrote a documentation for an application in LaTex, and was wondering what the best way to display in a webpage. I can just convert it to HTML, but I'm wondering if there's a better way with all the nice css styling done automatically as in other web documentations.

I'm looking for something like Sphinx, but never used it, so not sure if it's a good solution to a document already made in .tex/.pdf

Comment: Why you don't Embed PDF in Webpage ??

Comment: Sphinx uses reStructuredText and generates HTML and PDF documentation out of that. I'm not sure if you want to rewrite your LaTeX file, but reStructuredText is really easy to work with.

Comment: @Pamma , just because it's ugly and.. idk, looks old agish :)

Comment: @Blender, Thank you, I DO NOT want to re write, but i'll take a look and see if want to redo it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did, (thx @Blender)

Exported the Latex file to html using tex4ht (texmaker) and used [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to convert the html file to reStructuresText, and edited that .rst to fit the specifications of [sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/). This was needed since I wanted to break the latex file to few different HTML files.

Then used sphinx to generate the PDF file. I think I'm going to keep writing in .rst, so it's easy to convert both to HTML, and PDF.

Adding the answer so anyone having the same problem will get some ideas.